# Android drag image

Tags: android, touch, imageview, drag

i have one imageview and one textview in my layout, and i wanto move this imageview with touch. Its work, but the problem is the textview move too , can u tell me how to fix it?

This is my code

```
private ImageView img;
private int status=0;
TextView tv;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            status=1;

        return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if( status==1)
    {
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.topMargin=(int)event.getRawY();
        lp.leftMargin=(int)event.getRawX();
        img.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
    status=0;
    }
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

}
}

And this is My XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Please include the XML file of your layout

Comment: What happens when you remove the line: android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"

Comment: yeah i got it, i realize it when i open my XML, thanks @T Dezentje

Answer (score 0):

Case Closed, OMG i forgot because i use relative layout and the textview is alignleft to imageview1 
Thanks for Help